# Limit Superior and Limit Inferior of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

I am taking an introductory course in Real Analysis and

$(i)$ My textbook gives the following definition of a limit superior $U$ which satisfies the following conditions:

> $(a)$ For every $\epsilon>0$,there exists an integer $N$ such that $n>N \implies a_n<U+\epsilon$
>
> $(b)$ Given $\epsilon>0$ and given $m>0$, there exists an integer $n>m$ such that $a_n>U-\epsilon$

$(ii)$ An another textbook gives the following definition of a limit superior of a sequence :

> The highest limit point of a given sequence is called the limit superior of the sequence.

$(iii)$ I read somewhere else that :

> limit superior is the infimum of those real numbers $v$ with the property that there are a finite number of natural numbers $n$ such that $v <x_n$.
>
> **EDIT : Attempt:** Suppose $x_n>v$ for infinite terms of the sequence $X=\{x_n\}$ and $v$ is the highest limit point of the sequence.
>
> I was thinking of making use of Bolzanno Weirstrass Theorem, but we would need $X$ to be bounded for that. How do I bring a contradiction?

I am confused about these definitions and not able to make any connection between definitions $(i),(ii),(iii)$.

Why is it the highest limit point and contain only a finite number of points of the sequence to the right?

How do I prove that these all are equivalent?

Thank you for your help..

Comment: Maybe you can show that all these conditions are equivalent to $\limsup a_n = \inf_{n\in \mathbb N} \sup_{m \geq n} a_m$

Comment: Uhmm .. Thank you for the comment. Could you please give me any hints?

Comment: For example for $(i)$: To prove $(a)$ let $\epsilon > 0$. Then $U< U + \epsilon$ and hence there is some $N \in \mathbb N$ with $\sup_{n \geq N} a_n < U + \epsilon$. This means for all $n \geq N$ that $a_n \leq \sup_{n \geq N} a_n < U + \epsilon$.

Comment: I think condition i) is not well expressed or my have a typo. Did you mean to write $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [\sup_{m \geq n} x_m] $?